# PHP Woes with font display

Tags: php, jquery, fonts

I'm building a two column content section on my website that allows a user to select an example of a font, enter a string of text, and click a button in the right column and in the left display the selected font and text the user has chosen.

I have looked at the PHP website and don't even know where to start. I'm used to dealing with databases and forms in PHP for gathering data but have never attempted something like this before.

I feel like it should be pretty simple so any help or hints are appreciated.

I would like to use fonts from: http://www.tattoo-fonts.com

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for, and you likely misunderstand how the site works. Please read [ask] to see how a question should look like.

Comment: You are looking for `imagettftext()`. Do a `<img>` DOM update onto the PHP script rendering the sample text, and that's it.

Comment: I should probably hit the books a little more.  Sorry for the confusing question.  tattoo-fonts.com is my website.  The left column has an input box, a color picker and bg colorpicker for now and the fonts below.  My question is how to get the input string and font selection to appear in the right column for each selected font.  I am looking into imagettftext() now.